# Resolve functions in JSON as static values

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a JSON object which includes a function, so a dynamic value which is reactive in Vue JS

```
{
  amount: 100,
  unit: 'mg',
  amountMg: function () {
     if (this.unit === 'mg') {
        return this.amount
     }
     if (this.unit === 'g') {
        return this.amount * 1000
     }
     if (this.unit === 'mcg') {
        return this.amount / 1000
     }
  },
}
```

Problem is I want to send this JSON object to an API but since the server is `Ruby` it won't recognize the `amountMg` value here. I first need to "resolve" this function as a static value so I kinda need to map the dynamic/reactive components of my JSON object so it would become this:

```
{
  amount: 100,
  unit: 'mg',
  amountMg: 100,
}
```

How is this possible? I could not figure out a proper solution other than manually manipulate each attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const newObj =  {
   amount: oldObj.amount,
   unit: oldObj.unit,
   amountMg: oldObj.amountMg()
}
// {
//  amount: 100,
//  amountMg: 100,
//  unit: "mg"
//}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gn6zxve2/16/)